# What are the differences between these two words?

Tags: synonyms

My question is about the differences between "heart" and "mind". I read many examples with these two words, yet I can't tell the differences between them when I see "greed in the heart" or "greed in the mind", and “you are always in my heart” or "you are always on my mind".

Comment: Water, where could you have been looking, that failed to show you a difference?

Will you please post the specific search keys you actually used?

Answer (score 0):

Heart is generally emotional, sentimental and viewed as authentic.

Mind is contemplative, visionary and intellectual.

Having someone's "best interests in mind" makes it sound as though the actor is going to be thinking of them in a concerned but detached manner. That statement makes it seem as though the concerns of the other person are an abstract problem to solve.

Having someone's "best interests at heart" implies that there is a deeper empathic relationship, and a more personal connection.

Comment: This is very good answer. Thanks. From your answer, I can safely assume that the sentense"you are always in my heart" is much stronger in emotion than "you are always on my mind".

Comment: Yep, "You are always on my mind" could be something an angry boss says to a troublesome employee, lol. Its still sentimental enough to be a bit too intimate for that context, but it is plausible. "You are always in my heart" is an intensely personal statement.